# using nested if in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure using nested if, but I am not getting how to frame it. Please help me out.
This if what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StarDistributorProfit 
@sponsorId varchar(20),

AS
if exists(select sponsor_id where(select count(user_id) from usertransaction where bv=50001))
    if count=1,TotalGBV=25000,TotalPBV=200
BEGIN
update usertransaction set rank='executive' where sponsor_id=@sponsorId
update usertransaction set dp=(0.309*BV)
update usertransaction set leadership_bonus=(0.07*BV)
END
if count=2,TotalGBV=20000,TotalPBV=200
BEGIN
update usertransaction set rank='star executive' where sponsor_id=@sponsorId
update usertransaction set dp=(0.318*BV)
update usertransaction set leadership_bonus=(0.03*BV)
END
if count=3,TotalGBV=20000,TotalPBV=300
BEGIN
update usertransaction set rank='Organizer' where sponsor_id=@sponsorId
update usertransaction set dp=(0.318*BV)
update usertransaction set leadership_bonus=(0.03*BV)
END 
GO
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data and expected results? It looks like what you're doing can probably be formulated in a single `UPDATE` statement, rather than first performing tests and then applying multiple updates. Also, I suspect quite a few of your `UPDATE`s are missing `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I am getting the following errors:    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.    An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for [`AND` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188372.aspx)...

For example `IF count=1 AND TotalGBV=25000 AND TotalPBV=200`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check multiple conditions, use `AND` between them - not a comma:

```
IF count = 1 AND TotalGBV = 25000 AND TotalPBV = 200
BEGIN
   UPDATE usertransaction SET rank = 'executive' WHERE sponsor_id = @sponsorId
   UPDATE usertransaction SET dp = (0.309 * BV)
   UPDATE usertransaction SET leadership_bonus = (0.07*BV)
END
-- and so forth for all your IF^s
```