# Updating multiple columns in a case statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, cursor

I want to check, if a sponsor has a user with a `TotalBV >= 50001` then the sponsor's `Rank, DP, Leadership_Bonus` will be updated with specific values

If there sponsor has 1 user whose `TotalBV >= 50001`, then update his records with the values in the first case statement.

If there sponsor has 2 users whose `TotalBV >= 50001`, then update his records with the values in the second case statement.. and so on

This is what I have done so far but I am getting errors in the update statement:

```
declare  @UserId varchar(50),@myInt int,@SponsorId varchar(50),@Rank varchar(50),@dp int,@LB int
declare c1 cursor READ_ONLY
for
set @myInt = (select COUNT(User_Id) from UserTransaction as count where @SponsorId='RL9058' and     TotalBV>=50001)

open c1

fetch next from c1
into @SponsorId,@UserId,@Rank

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

update UserTransaction set Rank,DP,Leadership_Bonus=(case 
when (@myInt=1 and TotalGBV=25000 and TotalPBV=200) then (Rank='executive' and DP=(0.309*BV) and     Leadership_Bonus=(0.07*BV))
when (@myInt=2 and TotalGBV=20000 and TotalPBV=200) then (rank='star executive' and dp=(0.318*BV) and leadership_bonus=(0.03*BV))
when (@myInt=3 and TotalGBV=20000 and TotalPBV=300) then (rank='Organizer' and dp=(0.327*BV) and leadership_bonus=(0.02*BV))
when (@myInt=4 and TotalGBV=15000 and TotalPBV=300) then (rank='Star Organizer' and dp=(0.336*BV) and leadership_bonus=(0.01*BV))
when (@myInt=5 and TotalGBV=15000 and TotalPBV=500) then (rank='Co-Ordinater' and dp=(0.345*BV) and leadership_bonus=(0.01*BV))
when (@myInt=6 and TotalGBV=10000 and TotalPBV=500) then (rank='Star Co-Ordinater' and dp=(0.354*BV) and leadership_bonus=(0.01*BV))
when (@myInt=7 and TotalGBV=10000 and TotalPBV=1000) then (rank='7Star Co-Ordinater' and dp=(0.360*BV) and leadership_bonus=(0.01*BV))
else null end)
where @SponsorId='RL9058'

FETCH NEXT FROM c1
into @UserId,@SponsorId,@Rank,@dp,@LB
END
close c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Comment: The error is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'

Comment: Why even use a **cursor** for this?? Avoid cursors like the plague! And here, you can *definitely* do without a cursor - and your code will be clearer and execute **much** faster!

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that evaluates to a single value - you **cannot** return multiple values, nor can you execute code fragments. You'll have to rewrite your code

Comment: how should I do it then? help me out

Comment: @marc_s I had done it the [other way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038976/using-nested-if-in-stored-procedure?noredirect=1#comment40788951_26038976) also(without using cursor) but got errors and couldnt figure out how to solve it. I thought using cursor would be an easier option